# how to stop player position from changing once it is against a wall/static-object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, controls, collision-detection

I am creating a top-down game, Though during testing I found that the enemies weren't going to the player.

I discovered that the coordinates of the player change when it moved, though the coordinates would still change when the player would move against the wall. for example, if I was to move up into a wall, even though the player wasn't moving, its Z coordinate would still be increasing

this is the code that is to move the player:

```
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        var dir = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical")).normalized;
        transform.Translate(dir * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
```

What I then wanted to try was adding a colliding feature to which if it notices that the player's side is touching a wall or static object which meant that it would shut off the ability to continue going in the direction that it is against until it was not touching the wall on the specific side.

though I couldn't get the collision/collider code to work, I found that it wasn't picking up that it was touching an object.

are there any methods to fix this issue?

Comment: Have you considered using a `Physics2D.Raycast` to detect whether the player will hit a wall? `RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(rayStart, rayDirection, maxRayDistance);` then   check if you hit a wall collider (via `tag`, `LayerMask` or other)

Comment: no I haven't, how do you use it, what is raystart/raydirection/maxraydistance?

Comment: Does a ray detect the distance from one point to another, in this situation, from player to wall?

Comment: Have a read over [Physics2D.Raycast](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.Raycast.html) documentation which should answer your questions. If you're still stuck after making an attempt, I'll provide an example :)

Comment: yeah I have had a look, also my game is in 3D, and i am struggling to understand it, i have tried typing some code `RaycastHit hit = Physics.Raycast(transform.position, new Vector3(0, Mathf.Atan2(dir.z, dir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg))` though im getting an error "Cannot implicitly convert type bool to raycasthit". also `new Vector3(0, Mathf.Atan2(dir.z, dir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg)` is stating the direction due to axis input

Comment: Physics.Raycast return a boolean indicating if a hit happened.  Use the out parameter for the raycast hit info.  `if (Physics.Raycast(...., out var hit)) .. `